# Why is this pattern discouraged in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: multithreading, sqlalchemy

When reading the official SQLAlchemy documentation, I found the example below:

```
### this is the **wrong way to do it** ###

class ThingOne(object):
    def go(self):
        session = Session()
        try:
            session.query(FooBar).update({"x": 5})
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise

class ThingTwo(object):
    def go(self):
        session = Session()
        try:
            session.query(Widget).update({"q": 18})
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise

def run_my_program():
    ThingOne().go()
    ThingTwo().go()
```

I don't really understand the drawbacks for this pattern. Actually I can think of one major ADVANTAGE to this: in a multi-threading context, this pattern can ensure that each session instance is a local variable to the function that actually uses it.

Could someone enlighten me by giving some potential drawbacks for the example above? Thanks.

Edit: As an example for advantages in a multiple threading context. If we have a web application server class here:

```
class WebApp:
  def update(self, **kwargs):
    session = Session()
    try:...
```

Here, the page handler `update` has its own local variable `session`, so no matter how many threads it runs, it's always safe. In constrast, using another layer of function to contain `session` would introduce way more complexity in this case

Comment: Why don't you quote the [proposed better solution from the documentation as well and the reasons given](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it).

Comment: @Ilja Everilä I didn't quote the `Do` example because it only shows an exact opposite solution. So I think quoting one side would be suffient to illustrate this problem. Even with that quoted, it still not quite clear what advantages it really gives you. It's just an abstract principle to separate the concerns. But in my case I need it absolutely thread safe, preferably without introducing another layer of complexity.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä why downvote my question? I tried to make a clear case to show a different view. Isn't this a kind of contribution to our knowledge base to better understand the dos and don'ts?

Comment: The drawbacks are explained in the documentation, or rather it is explained why the other pattern you did not quote is better. There's little gained in duplicating the official documentation here. This in my view moves this question to the category "does not show research effort / not useful". As for thread safety, neither pattern fails in that respect.

Comment: There's not much to understand, and you've presented no threading examples. The drawbacks include, but are not limited to, too tight coupling of session lifetime and handling objects. Another aspect that the "Don't" example fails is (easy) testability. Now you have to mock the global `Session`, instead of passing one to the function. It's doable, but more complex. Your code also could in some configurations fail your "is local variable" aspect, though not in a meaningful way; mainly if `Session` is actually a scoped session. Don't read too much in to downvoting. It's pretty far from tyranny.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä, fair enough, I've edited my question so it now at least has a little better emphasis on the threading scenario. Thanks for your last comment anyways.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä, +1 for the good point of testing. For the `scoped_session`, I think it's not a very strong case, as even with that you still need to instantiate it locally. Correct me if I'm wrong here but isn't local variable always thread-safe, provided that it's the only reference to a locally instatiated object? you can prove that by looking at the objects memory addresses, they are always stored in their own address. no mixing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151242/discussion-between-ilja-everila-and-jinghui-niu).

Answer (score -1):

In simple terms, sqlalchemy recommends that the handling of session is not mixed with the manipulation of data. As you can see from the next example.

```
### this is a **better** (but not the only) way to do it ###

class ThingOne(object):
    def go(self, session):
        session.query(FooBar).update({"x": 5})

class ThingTwo(object):
    def go(self, session):
        session.query(Widget).update({"q": 18})

def run_my_program():
    session = Session()
    try:
        ThingOne().go(session)
        ThingTwo().go(session)

        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

ThingOne and ThingTwo is just doing it's thing in doing CRUD but the handling of session is done outside of those objects.

For multi threading, session scopes are thread local objects. Meaning, they can't be shared by different threads. You can declare them as what you have specified but it doesn't mean that handling session from an external entity is bad choice either.

Comment: By "session scopes" do you mean a [scoped session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html)? The wording matters, since "session scopes" would imply that all sessions have thread local scope, which they don't.